# Getting error Makefile:45: invalid syntax in conditional. Stop

Tags: c++, ubuntu, openwrt

Now I'm learning c++. While trying to execute makefile, I'm getting error like this

**Makefile:45:  invalid syntax in conditional.  Stop.** 
My system configurations are :

- OS:- Ubuntu
- OpenWRT SDK

I'm trying to build the SDK in **ubuntu OS** system. 
Here I'm adding the makefile code, which I have tried.

```
    include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk
PKG_NAME:=helloworld
PKG_VERSION:=0.0.1
PKG_RELEASE:=1


PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)
include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk


define Package/helloworld

    SECTION:=base
    CATEGORY:=Utilities
    DEFAULT:=n
    TITLE:=This is my first project
    URL:=http://unwireddevices.com
    # Other packages your program needs (our doesn't need anything, so let's comment it out)
    # DEPENDS:=+libstdcpp
endef


define Package/helloworld/description
    This! Is! My! First! Project!
endef




define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/
endef


define Build/Configure
    $(call Build/Configure/Default,--with-linux-headers=$(LINUX_DIR))
endef



define Package/helloworld/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/bin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/helloworld $(1)/usr/bin/
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage, helloworld))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Makefile, first line seems to be over-indented.
Follow make file guidelines and use tabs and spaces properly.